# ¿Por qué se tomó la decisión de incorporar la línea del tiempo en las preguntas/respuestas? ¿Esto tiene algunas ventajas?

Tags: soporte, línea-de-tiempo

Desde hace un par de días veo que ahora en las preguntas/respuestas aparece acceso a la línea del tiempo desde el panel de la izquierda, tanto en Meta como en Stack Overflow. Por ejemplo en [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre COUNT(*), COUNT(1) y COUNT(columna)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130325/83) veo:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que lleva a https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/130325/timeline.

¿Cuándo se decidió hacer esta incorporación?

¿Por qué se decidió? ¿Aporta esto algunas ventajas? ¿Cuáles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se añadió un enlace directo [el 16 de enero de 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/209901) tras ser solicitado durante años en Meta.SE (antes solamente era accesible tecleando la dirección a mano, como otras descritas en la [Lista de direcciones no enlazadas de los sitios Stack Exchange](http://%20https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566/209901)). Por ejemplo, la propuesta que desencadenó la respuesta es [Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/209901) y tiene una puntuación de 140.

La línea de tiempo resulta muy útil para ver qué ha ocurrido en una publicación durante su historia de vida y ver cosas como:

- ediciones
- sugerencias de edición
- comentarios
- votos

Podría argumentarse que la vista de revisiones ya da información, pero es que esta da incluso más.

Esta funcionalidad ya estaba disponible para moderadores y créeme que la usan mucho (yo lo utilizaba bastante cuando era moderador, pues por ejemplo permitía ver en qué colas de revisión estaba una publicación en un momento dado, cosa que en la vista actual no está disponible para todos los usuarios).

Comment: Como aclaración, la linea temporal siempre ha estado disponible para usuarios no moderadores. Lo que no existía era un enlace directo a la misma, pero se podía acceder tecleando la url.

Comment: @Pikoh bien matizado, toda la razón